# Robot framework multiple devices testing using UI-Automator Library

Tags: robotframework, android-uiautomator

I have to create a test suite in robot framework using uiautomatorlibrary where I will be having 2 android device connected.

1. I wanted to open WhatsApp in both the devices and start messaging each other.
2. I want to send normal messages from one mobile another and vice versa.

Until now I have done automation using only one device. But I need to implement multi device testing in same test itself. But I don't want to use Appium for this test to happen. I want to use uiautomator library only.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to connect to more than 1 device using a single Library instance. This is also not a common approach in programming.

It is possible to load the same library twice and that way connect to two devices at the same time. Although I'm sure that there are examples on this site that show this, they're often in the context of a different question.

In the Robot Framework Guide there is a specific section on this topic: [Setting custom name to test library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-custom-name-to-test-library). It has the following example that the same library is loaded twice and that you can call keywords for specific instances using the `instance name.keyword` notation.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SomeLibrary    localhost        1234    WITH NAME    LocalLib
Library    SomeLibrary    server.domain    8080    WITH NAME    RemoteLib

*** Test Cases ***
My Test
    LocalLib.Some Keyword     some arg       second arg
    RemoteLib.Some Keyword    another arg    whatever
    LocalLib.Another Keyword
```

This can be used to create an instance for each device and then use the keywords for each instance to send a message and verify the receipt of it on the other device from within the same script.

Comment: I want to use robotframework-uiautomatorlibrary itself. and only one instance of the library. and, here i want to use two devices connected. I was trying set serial number, can i do the operation by setting serial number of device ? if yes, please help me with sample code.

Comment: Please update your question if you have a specific technical reason why you think a single instance is necessary, desirable or preferred.

Comment: In the event that you feel an answer requires a down vote, please provide a comment for the motivation of it.